# Knockout memory crash issue

Tags: knockout.js

I am using KO for updating rows of an observable table.
The table is generated and works for data array less than 700, but the page crashes when data is larger say > 1000.

I am not sure how to prevent this issue. 
Here is the code where the crash occurs.

```
self.testcase = ko.observableArray([]);
self.loadDetailData = function (type, entity, criteria) {
self.testcase.removeAll(); toastr.clear();
UI.toastrPopUp("info", 'Getting information...', '', null, 'progressbar');
fetchResults(type, entity, criteria).done(function (data) {          
    if (data != "")
    {   
        var testInstances = data.map(function (item) {
               return (new test(item));
         });            
        self.testcase(testInstances);//crashes here if data ~ 1000
        console.log(self.testcase());
        toastr.clear();
            }
        else {
             toastr.clear();
             UI.toastrPopUp("error", 'Error...', '', null, 'error');
        }

   }).fail(function (data) {
        toastr.clear();
   });
```

Comment: It may be too heavy to render so much data on a page. You need to consider some paging.

Comment: Normally 700 items are not that much of a load to cause a complete crush... can you post items structure and html bind as well?